# How to extract Cohort analysis in SQL ? or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking at other posts was not working due to my lack of ability .
I am trying to extract a Cohort from the date of installation .

information TABLE

1. u_status
   used  : created_at , last_login
2. u_daily_login

SQL

```
SET
    @targetDate = '2020-07-01'; 
SELECT
    @Datecount := TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        DAY,
        @targetDate,
        DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')) -1;
    SELECT
        dl.df,
        COUNT(udl.uMasterId)
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            DATE_FORMAT(
                DATE_ADD(
                    @targetDate,
                    INTERVAL td.generate_series DAY
                ),
                '%Y-%m-%d'
            ) AS df
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                0 generate_series
            FROM DUAL
        WHERE
            (@num := 1 -2) * 0
        UNION ALL
    SELECT
        @num := @num +1
    FROM
        `information_schema`.COLUMNS
    WHERE
        @num <= @Datecount
        ) AS td
    ) AS dl
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT udlt.*
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            u_daily_login
        WHERE
            DATE >= @targetDate
    ) AS udlt
INNER JOIN(
        /*基準日に登録したユニークユーザー*/ SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            DATE_FORMAT(us.`createdAt`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS cdate,
            us.name,
            uMasterId
        FROM
            u_status AS us
        WHERE
            DATE_FORMAT(us.`createdAt`, '%Y-%m-%d') = @targetDate
    ) AS noise
GROUP BY
    noise.name
    ) AS uus
ON
    uus.uMasterId = udlt.uMasterId
) AS udl
ON
    dl.df = udl.date
GROUP BY
    dl.df
LIMIT 100;
```

I got the desired result,　As it is now, I'm typing `targetDate` manually.

```
ex. @targetDate =  2020-07-02 , "targetDate = 2020-07-03  ...etc
```

How can I efficiently extract daily cohorts?

Comment: sorry bros..  /*基準日に登録したユニークユーザー*/ 
is 
/ * Unique user registered on the reference date * /

Comment: i`ll try this  .
"""
SELECT
    MONTH(createdAt),
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    SUM(
        lastLogin >= DATE(createdAt) - INTERVAL DAY(createdAt) - 1 DAY
    ) AS day1,
    SUM(
        lastLogin >= DATE(createdAt) - INTERVAL DAY(createdAt) - 2 DAY
    ) AS day2,
    SUM(
        lastLogin >= DATE(createdAt) - INTERVAL DAY(createdAt) - 3 DAY
    ) AS day3
FROM
    u_status
WHERE
   createdAt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY
GROUP BY
    MONTH(createdAt),
    DAY(createdAt) """

Comment: . . Your question needs to include sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what *you* mean by "cohort analysis".